# Blackbox Scripts in Google Chrome's Performance Recorder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, developer-tools

When debugging on Chrome Developer Tools you can set a .js (.ts, ...) file as blackbox. Debug will not step into a blackbox file.

This is very nice. But I want/need more. When using Performance tab and recording some actions, chrome collect all events and codes runned (regardless of blackboxing).

Is there a way to filter a record or record respecting blackbox? (Or something with the same effect).